# Module of finite cardinality and local lenghts.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ an $A$-module such that $\#(M)$ is finite  and $A$ is a Noetherian integral domain of dimension $1$. Moreover suppose that for any nonzero prime $\mathfrak p \subset A$ we have $\#(A/\mathfrak p)<\infty$.
The following equality is well known:

$$\operatorname{length}_A(M)=\sum_{\mathfrak p} \operatorname{length} _{A_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p})\quad\quad(\ast) $$

where the sum is over all nonzero prime ideals of $A$.

I'd like to understand how I can get the following expression of $\log(\#(M))$ by using just $(\ast)$ and the hypotheses:

$$\log(\#(M))=\sum_{\mathfrak p} \operatorname{length} _{A_{\mathfrak p}}(M_{\mathfrak p})\cdot\log(\#(A/\mathfrak p))$$

I suppose that the answer should be very easy but I really don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate to reduce to the case $M=M_P$ for some $P\neq 0$. In that case, $\#(M)= \#(A/P)^{\mathrm{length}\, M}$.